IF statement reading the last in the series
Strange one here, I've got a variable racks_value which has it's value altered on the page, depending on various calculations (yes it's an integer and not a string). I've got a series of IF statements that updates the value of another variable, depending on the value of racks_value.
Now here's the strange part - even though I've manually declared here in the example below that racks_value = 2 and had a console log verify this, after the IF statements have been run, the second console log shows racks_value to be 20, when it should still be 2. You can copy/paste the code below into your console of any page and it will behave the same way.
There must be something simple and obvious that I've missed here, but I really can't see it, as the code looks so straightforward and simple.
var racks_value = 2;
console.log('racks value is ' + racks_value);

if (racks_value = 1){ var upfront_racks = 1000; }
if (racks_value = 2){ var upfront_racks = 2000; }
if (racks_value = 3){ var upfront_racks = 3000; }
if (racks_value = 4){ var upfront_racks = 4000; }
if (racks_value = 5){ var upfront_racks = 5000; }
if (racks_value = 6){ var upfront_racks = 6000; }
if (racks_value = 7){ var upfront_racks = 7000; }
if (racks_value = 8){ var upfront_racks = 8000; }
if (racks_value = 9){ var upfront_racks = 9000; }
if (racks_value = 10){ var upfront_racks = 10000; }
if (racks_value = 11){ var upfront_racks = 11000; }
if (racks_value = 12){ var upfront_racks = 12000; }
if (racks_value = 13){ var upfront_racks = 13000; }
if (racks_value = 14){ var upfront_racks = 14000; }
if (racks_value = 15){ var upfront_racks = 15000; }
if (racks_value = 16){ var upfront_racks = 16000; }
if (racks_value = 17){ var upfront_racks = 17000; }
if (racks_value = 18){ var upfront_racks = 18000; }
if (racks_value = 19){ var upfront_racks = 19000; }
if (racks_value = 20){ var upfront_racks = 20000; }
    
console.log('racks value is ' + racks_value);

I've tried changing the = to ===, but it doesn't appear to help. If another new line for the IF statement series is added, the lower console log message will then return the new one.

racks_value = 1 and so on, is assignment - and since you always assign a "tuthy" value, all conditions are true - use == or === as appropriate

Argghhh gosh, I tried that but only for the first two in the series. Thank you - your suggestion solved it right away.

I don't know how to select your response as the answer :(

you can't - it's not an answer as such anyway

Why not just check racks_value is in range (using < and > operators), and then set var upfront_racks = 1000 * racks_value; ..?

I have copy pasted your code, it shows me 'racks value is 20'.
Reason is on your last line you are assigning "racks_value = 20". Which is correct output
Issue is all your if conditions should use "==" (not "="). If you change your assignment code to == then the result will be 'racks value is 2'
after running the script
